# python and windows file systems : check filename exists inside a zip archive

Tags: python, windows, zip

Working under windows with python 2.x, files on local drives (not UNC).

It seems ziplib stores filenames inside the zip archive stripping the drive letter and converting the path separator:

> C:\msala\test.txt --> msala/test.txt

Questions:

1. is this behaviour compliant with the specifications of the zip file format, or just a caveat of ziplib ?
2. how can I check if a given filename is in the archive ?

I prefer to avoid this ugly hack:

```
if sys.platform == "win32" :
    if filename[1:3] == ":\\" :
        filename = filename[3:]
    filename = filename.replace(os.sep, '/')

if filename in zfh.namelist() :
```

IMHO it is very un-pythonic (batteries included ?!) to have to manage this...

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: from 4.4.17 (https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

> All slashes
>          MUST be forward slashes '/' as opposed to
>          backwards slashes '\' for compatibility with Amiga
>          and UNIX file systems etc.

Question 2: many ways to do this, e.g.

```
zip_filename = os.path.splitdrive(filename)[1].replace('\\', '/')
```

(should work equally well on windows paths on windows and linux paths on linux).

Comment: mmh do you find anything about the stripping of the drive letter ?

Comment: See updated answer. Note: it will not work for windows paths on linux, ie. `os.path.splitdrive(r'c:\users\bjorn')` returns `('', 'c:\\users\\bjorn')` on linux (and wsl).

Comment: You should probably pay attention to Eren's answer here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846000/file-separators-of-path-name-of-zipentry